# Identify uninstallation of my app

Tags: android

I am doing an app in which i have to identify and notify me in any way(by SMS/MAIL/webservice call) that the user has uninstalled my app from his/her device.

Comment: You can see the android market statistics.

Comment: What do you want to do - yell at him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfect world its possible as you can detect removal via broadcast event but your application will never receive or have a chance to act on it. You would need to use a second app, which may be possible in a business situation. The average consumer will not want to install two apps and this also represents a security risk to consumers.

Answer (score 5):

Straight answer. Not possible.